# Replace the inner occurrence of an expression

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

I'm working on a piece of Python code using regular expressions and I'm trying to achieve the following:

If I have a piece of SQL as a string that contains some code in `[]` and a `WHERE` clause in front of it, I want to remove the complete `WHERE` clause. For example:

```
where this condition and [this = 1] group by 1,2,3
```

becomes

```
group by 1,2,3
```

The code I'm using is:

```
txt = """where [this = 1] group by"""

txt = re.sub("where.*\[.*\].*group" , 'group', txt, flags = re.S|re.I)
```

However, if I have another `WHERE` clause before this one the whole regex doesn't work as expected, e.g.:

```
txt = """where that and that do that where [this = 1] group by 1,2,3"""

txt = re.sub("where.*\[.*\].*group" , 'group', txt, flags = re.S|re.I)
```

produces

```
group by 1,2,3
```

instead of

```
where that and that do that group by 1,2,3
```

Edit: the solution should also work for a scenario like this:

```
txt = """where that and that do that where [this = 1] and [that = 1] group by 1,2,3"""
```

outputs:

```
"""where that and that do that group by 1,2,3"""
```

So it removes the inner (closest to `[]`) `WHERE` clause and all code containing at least one `[]` until the next `GROUP`, `ORDER` or `end of string`.

Finally, the solution needs to takes care of cases in which there are multiple such `where .. [...]` snippets in the string.

```
txt = """where [Include_Fakes|TRUE] group by 1 order by 1,3 ) where signed_up_date >= dateadd('[aggregation]', -[Last_N_Periods|12], CURRENT_DATE)"""

expected output:
group by 1 order by 1,3 )
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that.

```
exp =r"(where((?!where).)*\[.*?\].*?(?=(group|order)))|(where((?!where).)*\[.*?\].*$)"

txt = """where that and that do that where [this = 1] and [that = 1] group by 1,2,3"""
print(re.sub(exp, "", txt))
# ==> where that and that do that group by 1,2,3

txt = """where that and that do that where [this = 1] group by 1,2,3"""
print(re.sub(exp, "", txt))
# ==> where that and that do that group by 1,2,3

txt = """lots of code where signed_up_date >= dateadd('[aggregation]', -[Last_N_Periods|12], CURRENT_DATE)""" 
print(re.sub(exp, "", txt))
# ==> lots of code 

txt = """where [Include_Fakes|TRUE] group by 1 order by 1,3 ) where signed_up_date >= dateadd('[aggregation]', -[Last_N_Periods|12], CURRENT_DATE)"""
print(re.sub(exp, "", txt))

# ==> group by 1 order by 1,3 ) 

txt =  """where [condition1] group by 1) where [condition2] group by 2"""
print(re.sub(exp, "", txt))

# ==> group by 1) group by 2
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if I had multiple `[]`, i.e.
`re.sub(r"where((?!where).)*?]\s?", "", "where this condition and [this = 1] and [that = 1] group by 1,2,3")`
doesn't produce the desired output

Comment: It would be great if the question would describe this scenario, with an example and expected output.

Comment: this seems almost right - however, it somehow doesn't work in this case
`real_code = """lots of code where signed_up_date >= dateadd('[aggregation]', -[Last_N_Periods|12], CURRENT_DATE)"""
reg = re.sub(r"where\s+\[.*\]\s.*", "", real_code, flags = re.S|re.I)`

Comment: What would you like to see in this case? The bracket doesn't come immediately after the "where" statement.

Comment: "lots of code" would be the desired output. In my original question by 'in front of it' I didn't imply that 'WHERE' should be immediately in front of an expression '[]'. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Some of the code you want to remove in this case is not in brackets. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Yes. More generally, if a 'WHERE' clause contains at least one expression in brackets, I want to remove the complete 'WHERE' clause. In my case, 'WHERE' clause is limited by 'GROUP', 'ORDER' or end of string. That's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: So ... to make sure I get it right. The part you'd like to remove (1) begins with a 'where'; (2) contains some text something in brackets. (3) ends with group by / order by / the end of the string. Correct? And a question - what happens if you have 'group by' within the brackets?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. 'group by' can't be inside the squared brackets as '[ ]' can only contain a filter which will be inside a where clause. Another example:
`some code
where field1 = 'hello'
and [created_at::DATE=daterange]
group by 1
some more code`
becomes
`some code
group by 1
some more code`

Comment: I think I just found a counter-example for when this regex doesn't work as expected:

""where  [Include_Fakes|TRUE]
group by 1
order by 1,3
)
where signed_up_date >= dateadd('[aggregation]', -[Last_N_Periods|12], CURRENT_DATE)""

"should end up with group by 1
order by 1,3" but it produces an empty string - so it seems that the double appearance of "where ... []" causes an issue

Comment: Looking at it. This means that you can have multiple instances of where followed by brackets, each ending with group / order / end of expression. Right?

Comment: I believe your last version only works if the second occurrence of "where [condition]" is followed by end of string expression. If you simply add 'group by' at the end of the last "txt" it returns 'group by' instead of "group by 1 order by 1,3 ) group by", so the regex basically skips the inner clause. At this point I'm not really sure that I understand how to fix this...

Comment: similar happens in this case:
real_code = """WHERE text
where [aggregation]
group by 1
order by 1 desc""" 
print(re.sub(exp, r"", real_code, flags = re.S|re.I))

>> group by 1
order by 1 desc

Comment: Hmm. I'll look into it.

Comment: As to the last one, it seems to be fine. There are TWO where expressions. One with brackets, which is removed, and the other without - and this one stays there.

Comment: you're right. But the regex removed BOTH 'where' while it should only touch the one that is followed by [aggregation], correct? so "where text where [aggregation] group by 1 order by 1 desc" becomes "where text group by 1 order by 1 desc"

Comment: did you have a chance to look into it? I'm kinda stuck why it doesn't remove consequent occurrences of 'where [filter]'...

Comment: This is the output I'm seeing: 'where text group by 1 order by 1 desc'. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to my first comment from yesterday:
txt = """where [condition1] group by 1) where [condition2] group by 2""" returns group by 2 instead of "group by 1) group by 2", so it "swallows" the inner part

Answer (score 3):

You can use negative lookaheads to find the last possible match:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"where((?!where).)*?]\s?", "", "where that and that do that where [this = 1] group by 1,2,3")
'where that and that do that group by 1,2,3'
>>> re.sub(r"where((?!where).)*?]\s?", "", "where this condition and [this = 1] group by 1,2,3")
'group by 1,2,3'
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/5URfiN/2)

Comment: this wouldn't work if I had multiple `[]`, i.e.
`re.sub(r"where((?!where).)*?]\s?", "", "where this condition and [this = 1] and [that = 1] group by 1,2,3")`
doesn't produce the desired output

Comment: If you want to greedily match until the last `]`, just change the `*?` into a `*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the last occurrence of where using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) and then match any char except `[` or `]`.

Then repeat matching from an opening till closing `[` `]` and repeat that match 1+ times.

```
\bwhere(?:(?:(?!where)[^][])*\[[^][]*])+\s*
```

- `\bwhere` Word boundary and match where
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!where)[^][]` Match any char except `[` or `]` if on the right is not `where`
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\[[^][]*]` Match 0+ times any char except `[` or `]`
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to match at least one time `[`...`]`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9j0wMo/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OKA1c8)

Example code

```
import re
 
regex = r"\bwhere(?:(?:(?!where)[^][])*\[[^][]*])+\s*"
txt = ("where this condition and [this = 1] group by 1,2,3\n"
    "where that and that do that where [this = 1] and [that = 1] group by 1,2,3")
result = re.sub(regex, "", txt)
 
print (result)
```

Output

```
group by 1,2,3
where that and that do that group by 1,2,3
```